# Find Out Default Font Size of Title for UITabBar?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController. It has two tabs. They are labelled "FirstTitle" and "SecondTitle." How can I find out what the default font size for these titles are?

In ViewDidLoad, for my first View Controller, which corresponds to my first tab, I have tried:

```
print(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].titleTextAttributes(for: 
.normal))
print(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].titleTextAttributes(for: 
.selected))
let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
print(appearance.titleTextAttributes(for: .normal))
```

All of these return "nil." In addition, there is no default font size for the tab bar shown anywhere in Main.storyboard.

Answer (score 6):

1. Break the program with **Debug View Hierarchy** button
2. Select the UITabBarButtonLabel of your choice
3. Open the **Object inspector**
4. Discover that on iOS 12, the default is:

   > the system font (San Francisco) with a size of 10 and a weight of medium.

You also have the color, alignment and other useful informations.

[image]